# TCP connection between Android client and Windows server breaks after random time

Tags: java, android, tcp

I created a distributed application in Java for a Android client and PC server (in my case Windows). Android is supposed to hold the connection permanently to be able to receive push notifications. So there is a background service which survives switching off the screen. (Please do not tell me to use GCM. It is out-of-scope because I have to Internet connection.) For testing, the client sends every 5 minutes a self-made (application layer) `ping packet` to the server, which the server sends (after a delay) back as `pong` which in return is acknowledged (`ack`). When Server receives ack, delay is increased by 25 seconds.

However, randomly - as it seems - the server claims that the client has ungracefully closed the connection with this error message:

```
android java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I noticed that there are some factors which delay (not solve!) this problem:

- Other wifi network activity on the same wireless network AP.
- Activating and starting the Google Services Framework on the Android device.
- Setup a SSH tunnel via cygwin/ssh and connecting to server via this tunnel.

Following components I determined to have no impact:

- Oracle JDK versus openJDK (both version 7, 32bit, Windows)
- Network card (tried different USB wifi sticks as well as cable)
- Wifi APs (used DWL-2100AP, Netgear WGT624 v2, FritzBox 6360)
- Using Galaxy Nexus (4.3) vs using Galaxy Nexus 4 (4.2.2)

*If I run the server program on a Linux (Ubuntu) machine, there are no connection failures.*

What could be the reason for these connection problems? How can I get rid of them without switching to Linux?

Comment: Have you tried this on Older OS 4.0 for lower. This might be happen when your device is terminating connection to reduce power usage you may try [PowerManager.WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot research I came up with the solution myself...

One of the major issues here is the `deep sleep` which Android devices enter when they are not actively used. I do not want to use wake locks to not decrease battery live. I did not find a proper description of Android's deep sleep mode, however, it is mentioned in the [SystemClock documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html).

However, the deep sleep is not a problem for wifi communication in general. Android somehow manages to receive network packets also in deep sleep but does not necessarily wake up the receiving app. Instead they are delivered to the app when it becomes active anyways (e.g., due to user interaction or an alarm event).

An issue arises when using Windows because since Windows Vista and 2008 the timeout for ARP cache entries has been lowered to 15-45 seconds ([1.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2008/09/13/arp-cache-timeout-changed-in-windows-vista-and-2008/)). This means Windows asks about every 30 seconds for the MAC address of the Android device. This can be confirmed using a network sniffer. ("Who has 192.168.0.3? Tell 192.168.0.2")

If Android is sleeping it will not respond. After some timeout between 30 and 300 seconds (I could not determine it any more precise), apparently Windows declares all open TPC connections as broken. (That is were the IOException from above is coming from.)

So the solution is either to staticly set an ARP entry for the Android device ([2.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tips-flush-the-arp-cache-in-windows-7/)) or to massively increase the ARP cache timeout ([3.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949589)).

Let's first try the second approach:
Open `cmd` as admin and get network interface id:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces
```

Use id (here 11) to increase timeout base value (default: 30000):

```
netsh interface ipv4 set interface 11 basereachable=3000000
```

I also increased to retransmission interval (default: 1000)

```
netsh interface ipv4 set interface 11 retransmittime=10000
```

Confirm by entering `netsh interface ipv4 show interface 11`:

```
Interface Local Area Connection Parameters
----------------------------------------------
IfLuid                             : ethernet_6
IfIndex                            : 11
State                              : connected
Metric                             : 20
Link MTU                           : 1500 bytes
Reachable Time                     : 2850000 ms
Base Reachable Time                : 3000000 ms
Retransmission Interval            : 10000 ms
...
```

1. http://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2008/09/13/arp-cache-timeout-changed-in-windows-vista-and-2008/
2. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tips-flush-the-arp-cache-in-windows-7/
3. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949589

**EDIT**

While increasing these timeout values substantially enhances the situation, the same problem can still occur. So this gets even more technical:

It seems that the ARP timeout under Linux is specified in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/eth0/gc_stale_time` which defaults to 60 seconds. So this value is comparable to the Windows default.

The major difference, however, is the ARP implementation:

When Windows needs to send an IP package and the ARP cache timeout out for that entry, it **broadcasts** a request "Who has IP? Tell me". When Linux wants to do it, it uses the **last known MAC address** and uses it as receiver for the request "Who has IP? Tell me". (This is called a unicast poll and defined in RFC 1122, section 2.3.2.1 (2) --> ([1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-23)) )

Apparently, Android considers unicast requests more important than a broadcast (to address FFFFFF:FFFFFF) and answers immediately (so it rises from deep sleep to do so). The result: Linux immediately gets an ARP answer, while Windows doesn't and consequently kills all TCP connections for that MAC address.

1. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-23

**EDIT2**

I found another solution approache:

Make client broadcast its own MAC regularly (more frequent than the ARP cache times out on the server). This can be done using `arpping -c 1 -A -I wlan0 192.168.0.4`. Biggest problem here: arpping is not available on Android and Java does not support sending ARP packets. As I do not want a native implemention, I try my second approach from above.

Set static route on Windows server:

This find out network interface name: `netsh interface show interface` e.g. "Local Area Connection". Then add static ARP route: `netsh interface ip add neighbors "Local Area Connection" "192.168.0.4" "a0-0b-ba-44-f9-3d"`

**CONFIRMED**

Just wanted to confirm that using a static ARP route as described above fixes the problem. No connection failures. In my test I sent at least every 5 minutes one message either to server or to Android client. No packet was lost. Test duration: 10.5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem on OS Version 4.3. I am assuming that you are working on service this snippet might help you to keep your connection alive

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
public override void OnCreate ()
{
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
   mWakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock (WakeLockFlags.Partial, "PartialWakeLockTag");
   mWakeLock.Acquire();
}

public override void OnDestroy ()
{
     mWakeLock.Release();
}
```

Obviously by keeping your device CPU active you will drink your battery juice fast